# How to run MongoDB query in Ruby to find Embedded Document with null field?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

The following works to find Embedded Document bars with rsvp = yes:

```
foos = MongoMapper.database[ 'foos' ]

cursor = foos.find({ 'bars.rsvp' => 'yes'   },
                   { :fields => [ 'bars.$' ]})
```

How to find bars with rsvp nil or no rsvp key ***in Ruby***?

FWIW, the following seems to work in the Mongo console:

```
db.foos.find({ 'bars.rsvp' : null }, { bars: { $elemMatch: { 'rsvp' : null}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your english description, I think that this is what you want.

```
cursor = foos.find( { '$or' => [ { 'bars.rsvp' => nil }, { 'bars.rsvp' => { '$exists' => false } } ] } )
```

Here's a complete test script.

```
# rails c
foos = MongoMapper.database[ 'foos' ]
docs = [
    { 'bars' => { 'x' => 1, 'rsvp' => 'yes' } },
    { 'bars' => { 'x' => 2, 'rsvp' => nil } },
    { 'bars' => { 'x' => 3 } }
]
foos.remove
foos.insert(docs)
cursor = foos.find( { '$or' => [ { 'bars.rsvp' => nil }, { 'bars.rsvp' => { '$exists' => false } } ] } )
cursor.to_a
```

Submitted to 'rails c', the result of the last line is the following.

```
=> [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('527020a97f11ba2138000002'), "bars"=>{"x"=>2, "rsvp"=>nil}}, {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('527020a97f11ba2138000003'), "bars"=>{"x"=>3}}]
```

Hope that this answers your question and that it helps.